# Gson doesn't complain when json property is a string without double quotes (Kotlin/Android)

Tags: android, json, gson

Through some db manipulation I ended up with a string that should be, by all accounts, invalid JSON, namely:

```
{
    "x": MOVIESTAR
}
```

I was expecting an exception in my app when deserializing the above but I realised that Gson automagic's this into a string when parsing to `JsonObject`, e.g. like so:

```
GsonBuilder()
.create()
.fromJson("{\"x\":MOVIESTAR}", com.google.gson.JsonObject::class.java)
```

If I then `.toString()` the above the new JSON is nicely formatted.

While it does help one of my use cases, this behaviour is strange and unexpected.

Is there a way to control this when creating `GsonBuilder()`?

I am using `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0` on Android and my code is in Kotlin (doubt those last two facts matter, but JIC).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonObject =  GsonBuilder()
        .create()
        .fromJson("{\"x\":MOVIESTAR}",JsonObject::class.java)
 Log.e("TAG",""+jsonObject.get("x"))
```

@zaitsman please above it's already return as jsonObject and you can get using their key, above code output is String value "MOVIESTAR"

Comment: This is exactly my problem. This should FAIL not return `JsonObject` because this JSON string is invalid. E.g. try it in the browser...